# SweetAlert - Change Color of Button

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm trying to change the color of the cancel button like I can for the confirm button but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
}, function (isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
    }
});
```

Comment: `cancelButtonColor` isn't an option in [the API](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Comment: I don't see that option in the docs. Maybe there it's not supported. You can always create your own class with CSS.

Comment: Try this.... https://jsfiddle.net/x20ra1o1/2/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are using this version of SweetAlert: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert and in the source JS file (https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js), there is no such parameter to change color of cancel button.

In the file you have used, the params are:

```
var defaultParams = {
  title: '',
  text: '',
  type: null,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  showConfirmButton: true,
  showCancelButton: false,
  closeOnConfirm: true,
  closeOnCancel: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'OK',
  confirmButtonColor: '#8CD4F5',
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
  imageUrl: null,
  imageSize: null,
  timer: null,
  customClass: '',
  html: false,
  animation: true,
  allowEscapeKey: true,
  inputType: 'text',
  inputPlaceholder: '',
  inputValue: '',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: false
};
```

May I suggest you to use this version of SweetAlert: https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2 as here the option to change the cancel button color is present.

You can modify the source code of the first JS file, however in the second version it is readily available.

There is always the option available to use CSS to modify button colors. But if you want to make it customizable using JS, then SweetAlert2 is a better alternative.

Comment: Here's the simple migration guide from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2: https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2

Comment: Is it possible to use rgba (values) instead?

Comment: Just a late comment, SWAL adds classes it doesn't use, like .confirm and .cancel, this can be defined on your stylesheets, but you need to set background to !important because SWAL (not sure i used swal2) puts background color on buttons directly in the element style attribute.

Answer (score 14):

[update => hover option]

Maybe it'll help someone who use 2nd version
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation

Javascript

```
swal({
    title: "Apakah anda yakin?",
    text: "Anda dapat mengaktifkannya lagi nanti...",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: {
        confirm : {text:'Ubah',className:'sweet-warning'},
        cancel : 'Batalkan'
    },
}).then((will)=>{
    if(will){
        $(".onoffswitch-checkbox").prop('checked',false);
    }else{
        $("#all_petugas").click();
    }
});
```

CSS

```
...
.sweet-warning{
 background-color: black;
 #or anything you wanna do with the button
}

.sweet-warning:not([disabled]):hover{
 #hover here
}
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. `buttons` property accepts an `Object` where you can define properties for each button individually. Extra points untuk pakai Bahasa Indonesia di contoh :)

Answer (score 10):

To have a custom Cancel button use the "customClass" function and build your css to target the cancel button.

JavaScript:

```
swal({   
title: "Are you sure?",   
   text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",   
   type: "warning",   
   showCancelButton: true,      
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
   cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",   
   closeOnConfirm: false,   
   closeOnCancel: false,
   customClass: "Custom_Cancel"
}, 
function(isConfirm){   
   if (isConfirm) {     
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");   
   } else {     
      swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");   
   } 
});
```

CSS:

```
.Custom_Cancel > .sa-button-container > .cancel {
   background-color: #DD6B55;
   border-color: #DD6B55;
}
.Custom_Cancel > .sa-button-container > .cancel:hover {
   background-color: #DD6B55;
   border-color: #DD6B55;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good option when we cant upgrade to SweetAlert 2. Very helpful and we can also customise the confirm button via css too using the `.Custom_Cancel` class.

Comment: We are still using the old version of sweetalert. We are in the process of upgrading sweetalert but this solution is perfect in the meantime. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

For those who want to use **[SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)**, for example:

You can also **[migrate from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)** as needed.

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this! ⚠️",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  // Background color of the "Confirm"-button. The default color is #3085d6
  confirmButtonColor: 'LightSeaGreen',
  // Background color of the "Cancel"-button. The default color is #aaa
  cancelButtonColor: 'Crimson',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
      type: 'success',
      title: 'Deleted!',
      text: "Your file has been deleted.",
      timer: 2000,
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

---

Upgrading to **[`v9.x`](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v9.0.0)** of SweetAlert2.

> **Breaking change** - rename `type` to `icon`

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this! ⚠️",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  // Background color of the "Confirm"-button. The default color is #3085d6
  confirmButtonColor: 'LightSeaGreen',
  // Background color of the "Cancel"-button. The default color is #aaa
  cancelButtonColor: 'Crimson',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Deleted!',
      text: "Your file has been deleted.",
      timer: 2000,
      showCancelButton: false,
      showConfirmButton: false
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try following.

```
SweetAlert.swal({
                        title: 'Thank you',
                        text: 'Thank you for using the quoting tool. Your Quote PDF has been downloaded. The quote has been sent to U.S. Legal for approval.',
                        type: 'warning',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Cancel',
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"});
```

Comment: How about the on-hover?

Answer (score 6):

Sweet Alert 1

In CSS you can do this:

```
.swal-button--confirm {
    background: #0a0;
}

.swal-button--cancel {
    background: #aaa;
}

.swal-button--danger {
    background: #a00;
}
```

Add this if you don't want the button flash when it clicked.

```
.swal-button--confirm:active {
    background: #0a0;
}

.swal-button--cancel:active {
    background: #aaa;
}

.swal-button--danger:active {
    background: #a00;
}
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your css to override sweetalert2 style:

```
.swal2-styled.swal2-cancel{
  background-color: #dc3545 !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't be the guy to add important. No-one likes that guy.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the class to each button

```
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-secondary',
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution I have found:

add this to app.css:

```css
.swal-modal {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.651);
        color: white;
    }
    .swal-text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 33px;
    }
    .swal-button {
        background-color: #ff2600;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `default` way of doing this. But, you can override the style with custom css..

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74agy8ew/1/

Answer (score 0):

confirmButtonColor is no longer used. Instead, you should specify all stylistic changes through CSS. As a useful shorthand, you can set dangerMode: true to make the confirm button red. Otherwise, you can specify a class in the button object.
[enter link description here](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs#buttons)

Comment: This answer is plagiarized.

Answer (score 0):

For Sweetalert2

```
Swal.fire({
  title: "Error!",
  text: "Image is not selected",
  icon: "error",
  confirmButtonText: "OK",
  showCloseButton:true,
});


css

.swal2-close{
 background-color:black;
 color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can do this

```
.sweet-alert button.cancel {
    background-color: #FE9475;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sweetalert2 v11.4.0

I use in js

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'My title',
  text: 'description',
  icon: 'success',
  buttonsStyling: false,
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'sweet-alert-button'
  },
})
```

In css

```
.sweet-alert-button {
  background: #fac62d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Change Color Of Button :**

```
 .swal2-confirm {
        background-color: #008cba !important;
    }
```

[image]